# Spring Session Attributes table name is case sensitive

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, mariadb, spring-session

I am running MariaDB on Ubuntu, which causes table names to be case sensitive. I am using the initialize-schema option on spring session. Here's my config:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
server.servlet.session.timeout=30m
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=spring_session
```

On Windows this works fine, because it is not case sensitive. However on Ubuntu I get the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'mytable.SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES' doesn't exist
```

and

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'mytable.spring_session_ATTRIBUTES' doesn't exist
```

However I checked the database and confirmed that the table was created with a lowercase name. I think this is a bug? So I manually renamed the table using:

```
rename table spring_session_attributes to SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES;
```

And I confirmed that it is working now.

My question is: How can I resolve this issue without manually altering the database?

Comment: disable mariadb to be case sensitive. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-case-sensitivity/.

Comment: or always refer to the same table name with the same case as it was created ([Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Postel's_law)).

Comment: Risky to mess with that case sensitivity setting.